# How to call function only for first time in loop

Tags: jquery, velocity.js

Here i have set of animations that will continue in loop and i am trying to call the function only on the first iteration and when the first iteration ends,the function should not be called anymore. How can i do that?

Here is my code

```
             var r5anim1 = function(){
                $(".r5").velocity({ 
                      opacity: 1,
                      scale: [1,0],
                    }, {
                    duration:300,
                    complete: function() {
                    r5anim2();
                    }
                });
             }  

            var r5anim2 = function(){
                $(".r5").velocity({ 
                  opacity: 0,
                },{
                    duration:200,
                    complete: function() {
                    r6anim1();
                    wishes() // here i have called the function which should execute only on first loop.
                }               
            });
            }

            var r6anim1 = function(){
                $(".r6").velocity({ 
                      opacity: 1,
                      scale: [1,0],
                    }, {
                    duration:300,
                    complete: function() {
                    r6anim2();
                    }
                });
             }  

            var r6anim2 = function(){
                $(".r6").velocity({ 
                  opacity: 0,
                },{
                    duration:200,
                complete: function() {                                         
                    r5anim1();       //on end this will start the loop again 
                }               
            });
            }




        /*****************this function should be called only for the first time******************/
        var wishes = function(){
            boolvalue = 0;
            $(".wishes").velocity({ 
                  opacity: 1,
                  scale: [1,0.4],
                }, {
                duration:600,
            });
         }  
        r5anim1();
```

Comment: Declare one temp variable outside loop and set default true and check it in loop if its true call function once its called function make it false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a global variable

```
var isTriggered = false;
```

test if isTriggered, if its not tigger call the function

```
if(!isTriggered)
 {
wishes()
}
```

change the variable to true in the wishes() function so the loops stops

```
function wishes() {
isTriggered = false;
//other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a variable which is accessible globally and default that to false

```
var isFunctionCalled = false;
```

Call that function only if the flag is false and change the flag to true when the functuon is called.

```
if(isFunctionCalled == false){
    wishes()
    isFunctionCalled = true;
}
```